# Calling a function within a function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a function and I am trying to call it within another onclick function.. but not able to do so, ideally when the first function is called it should pop up an alert. Below is the code...

First function:

```
<script>
    function test() {
       var $var1 = 'BollywoodNEntertainment';
        $('#grid').facebook_wall({
            id: $var1,
            access_token: '193673707489176|55a9bc60f1b35074263ea95e45218fc3',
            limit: 1

        });
    }
</script>
```

Calling the first function under second one

```
<script>
    var $test = $('#test');
    $test.on('click', function(){
      $('#div1').remove();  
      $('#div2').remove();  
      $('#div3').remove();  
      test();   
    });

</script>
```

When calling it like below it is working fine...

```
<div id = "grid">
<script>
        test();   
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't notice the parse error?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the variable name

```
  var $var1 = 'BollywoodNEntertainment';
  $('#grid').facebook_wall({
    id: $var1 ,
        access_token: '193673707489176|55a9bc60f1b35074263ea95e45218fc3',
    limit: 1
  });
```

Bind the click event in $(document).ready(), please see the following...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#test").on('click', function(){
     $('#div1').remove();  
     $('#div2').remove();  
     $('#div3').remove();  
     test();   
   });
 });
```

Comment: what error are you getting from the browser's developer console?

Comment: Ensure that the click event is under $(document).ready(function(){...})

Comment: The query for '#test' (missing in your code) will not return anything either if in the head.

Comment: @Hemant tried the code but still not working... when I added an alert in the first function it is working ...but I guess the javascript facebook_wall is not getting called correctly ....  when I am executing the test function individually it is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

remove ); after first function

```
    var var1='BollywoodNEntertainment'; 
$(function(){

function test() {


alert("reached");

        $('#grid').facebook_wall({
            id: var1,
            access_token:'193673707489176|55a9bc60f1b35074263ea95e45218fc3',
            limit: 1

        });
        }

$("#test").click(function(){
$('#div1').remove();   
 $('#div2').remove();   
 $('#div3').remove();   


    test();
});


            });
```

check this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheSniper102/z3fk780h/4/)

Comment: Demo in console` Uncaught ReferenceError: var1 is not defined`

Comment: you must define it global  after the script tag 
<script>

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>   
var $test = $('#test');    
$('#test').on('click', function(){
  $('#div1').remove();      
  $('#div2').remove();    
  $('#div3').remove();   
 test();    }); 
</script>    

<script>    
 function test() {        
  alert('hello');       
   var $var1 = 'BollywoodNEntertainment';
    $('#grid').facebook_wall({   
     id: $var1,            
     access_token: '193673707489176|55a9bc60f1b35074263ea95e45218fc3',  
       limit: 1     
        });  
      }</script>
```